# How to get custom fields list with describeSObject on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am using describeSObject to get the fields list of the object "contact".

However, while I have created some custom fields in the contact object, these custom fields don't appear in the fields list returned when looping on the fields property.

```
$fields = $mySforceConnection->describeSObject('contact');

foreach($fields->fields as $value){
    echo $value->name.' '.$value->label."\r\n";
}
```

When doing so I get all the default contact object fields, but not the custom fields I created for the object.

I can't find what I am not doing right, any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

describeSObject will return all fields (standard & custom) that you have access to, sounds like you might not of given your profile FLS (Field Level Security) access to your new fields.

Comment: In the "Set Field-Level Security" of the custom field , I have checked all the checkboxes and yet the custom field won't appear. Is there any other salesforce setting you could think of I should give a look? thanks

Comment: are you sure you're looking in the same org in both cases?